# Nginx: How to forward http://my_ipaddress to http://my_ipaddress:8001/v1/offer/1

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx and cannot configure nginx in my RHEL7.2.
below is my default.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d/. I want to forward mydomain/v1/offer/1 to mydomain:8001/v1/offer/1

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name octest.omniconnect.net;

    location ~ /(.*) {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8001/ $scheme://$host:80;
    }
}
```

When I tried with postman, getting error. Please help me to fix the error. thank you.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Do you want to forward, or do you want to proxy? They're completely different.